# Ruby on Rails: NoMethodError in PostsController#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, controller

I am trying to build a forum using Ruby on Rails every thing was working fine but then I decided to press the new post button and I got a error
can anyone help me I am new to this.

[image]

Comment: thats supposed tobe `@post = Post.new`

Comment: It seems your current_user is nil is your user logged in?

Comment: I think that maybe it lol that my user was not logged in I check that when I get home.

Comment: @Jules, you should post atleast a piece of code related to the image you posted above. So that we can investigate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to add `before_action :authenticate_user!` in **PostsController**

Answer (score 0):

Ur Current_User is nil somehow.

Either your session expired or something is wrong with your authentication.

Test this:
    <%= current_user.to_s %>

and see what you get.

Hope it Helped, Cheers